# displaying one div while hovering another one in html error

Tags: css

i have a section in html which is divided into two, in one section i am listing some points and in another i am displaying their corresponding sentance on hover, i did like the following:

```css
.showme {
  display: none;
}

.single-fun-fact:hover~.showme {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="company-groth section overlay-with-img gray-bg">
  <img src="UK STUDY-03.jpg" alt="" class="bg-img">

  <div class="company-groth">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="fun-fact">
            <div style="margin-top: -25%; margin-left: -5%;" class="section-head text-center">
              <h2>Highlights Of Study In UK</h2>
              <div class="section-divider">
                <div class="left wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.2s"></div>
                <span></span>
                <div class="right wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.2s"></div>
              </div>
              <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="hulk" class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">NO</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">IELTS REQUIRED</h2>
            </div>
            <!-- .single-fun-fact -->
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">NO</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">BACKLOGS COUNT</h2>
              <div class="showme1">
                <h2>And <b> Career Gap</b> is not an issue.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .single-fun-fact -->
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">SCHOLARSHIP</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 5%;">OPPORTUNITIES</h2>
              <div class="showme2">
                <h2>Upto 3000£ for your studies.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .single-fun-fact -->
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">QUICK</p>

              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">ADMISSION</h2>
              <div class="showme3">
                <h2>In UK admission decisions are much faster, so we can expect a decision in 2-3 weeks.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .single-fun-fact -->
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">CAN</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">WORK PART TIME</h2>
              <div class="showme4">
                <h2>20 hours per week during academic intakes and 40 hours during vacation.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .single-fun-fact -->
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">THREE</p>

              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">YEAR GRADUATION</h2>
              <div class="showme5">
                <h2>Most UK universities recognize the Indian education system of 3year graduation.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .single-fun-fact -->
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">SPOUSE</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">CAN TRAVEL</h2>
              <div class="showme6">
                <h2>Along with the student and can work full time.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .single-fun-fact -->
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">LOW</p>

              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">TUITION FEE</h2>
              <div class="showme7">
                <h2>High quality of education with low tuition fee.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .single-fun-fact -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .col -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="company-groth-graph-wrap">
            <div class="showme">
              <h2>If student has 60-65% above in Intermediate English.</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- .company-groth-graph-wrap -->
        </div>
        <!-- .col -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

but while hovering on the div, its not displaying the hidden div. please tell me what is wrong with my code. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because `.single-fun-fact` and `.showme` are not siblings, as the `~` operator requires them to be.

For this to work you need to amend your selector to include the sibling `.col-md-6` element:

```css
.showme {
  display: none;
}

.single-fun-fact:hover ~ .col-md-6 .showme {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hulk" class="single-fun-fact">
  <p class="counte">NO</p>
  <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">IELTS REQUIRED</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="company-groth-graph-wrap">
    <div class="showme">
      <h2>If student has 60-65% above in Intermediate English.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Given your updated HTML the problem is because you've used `.showme1`, `.showme2`, `.showmeN` classes instead of the *same* `.showme` class on all elements. Fix that and it works:

```css
.showme {
  display: none;
}

.single-fun-fact:hover .showme {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="company-groth section overlay-with-img gray-bg">
  <img src="UK STUDY-03.jpg" alt="" class="bg-img">

  <div class="company-groth">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="fun-fact">
            <div style="margin-top: -25%; margin-left: -5%;" class="section-head text-center">
              <h2>Highlights Of Study In UK</h2>
              <div class="section-divider">
                <div class="left wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.2s"></div>
                <span></span>
                <div class="right wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.2s"></div>
              </div>
              <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="hulk" class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">NO</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">IELTS REQUIRED</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">NO</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">BACKLOGS COUNT</h2>
              <div class="showme">
                <h2>And <b> Career Gap</b> is not an issue.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">SCHOLARSHIP</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 5%;">OPPORTUNITIES</h2>
              <div class="showme">
                <h2>Upto 3000£ for your studies.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">QUICK</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">ADMISSION</h2>
              <div class="showme">
                <h2>In UK admission decisions are much faster, so we can expect a decision in 2-3 weeks.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">CAN</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">WORK PART TIME</h2>
              <div class="showme">
                <h2>20 hours per week during academic intakes and 40 hours during vacation.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">THREE</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">YEAR GRADUATION</h2>
              <div class="showme">
                <h2>Most UK universities recognize the Indian education system of 3year graduation.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">SPOUSE</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">CAN TRAVEL</h2>
              <div class="showme">
                <h2>Along with the student and can work full time.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="single-fun-fact">
              <p class="counte">LOW</p>
              <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">TUITION FEE</h2>
              <div class="showme">
                <h2>High quality of education with low tuition fee.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="company-groth-graph-wrap">
            <div class="showme">
              <h2>If student has 60-65% above in Intermediate English.</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: in the code snippet here its working, but when i added it to my code its not working

Comment: hello, can you open a chat if possible, i will show you my code

Comment: In that case your HTML may not be as you've shown it in the question. Can you please check that the HTML matches exactly.

Comment: Well in your full HTML you don't use the `.showme` class, you use `.showme1`, `.showme2` etc

Comment: no actually, while copy pasting the code went missing, i will update the question again, thats not the problem

Comment: can you open chat bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202049/discussion-between-kingkhan-kkhan-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: thats not the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

HTML

```
<div id="hulk" class="single-fun-fact">
  <p class="counte">NO</p>
  <h2 style="margin-left: 15%;">IELTS REQUIRED</h2>

</div>
<!-- .single-fun-fact -->




<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="company-groth-graph-wrap">

    <div class="showme">
      <h2>If student has 60-65% above in Intermediate English.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .company-groth-graph-wrap -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.showme { display: none; } 
.single-fun-fact:hover + div div.showme { display: block; }
```

Comment: I think you may have forgotten: `.showme{ display: none;}`

Comment: i just give solution were the changes required. in your code you already have .showme{ display: none;} so i give only this line .single-fun-fact:hover + div div.showme { display: block; }. to update your code. Now again i updated the code as per your requirement.